# Export / import a useState altering utility function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little upload handler like this:

```
const handleUploadPhoto = filename => {
  setHasImage('has-image');
  setPostButtonState('');
  onAddedPhoto(filename);
  setPostImageFilename(filename);
};
```

I use it all over the place and I'd love to export it from a helpers.js file and import it wherever needed, but I'm not sure how to do that considering when the useState variables affected by it need to stay in the parent, not the imported helper.

```
const [postImageId, setPostImageId] = useState(null);
const [postImageFilename, setPostImageFilename] = useState(null);
const [postImageUrl, setPostImageUrl] = useState(null);
```

Is this kind of function just not a good candidate for export / import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your own hook that defines all of the state setters and takes the `onAddedPhoto` as a parameter:

```
const useImageStuff = (onAddedPhoto) => {
  const [hasImage, setHasImage] = useState('');
  const [postButtonState, setPostButtonState] = useState('');
  const [postImageFilename, setPostImageFilename] = useState('');
  const handleUploadPhoto = () => {
    setHasImage('has-image');
    setPostButtonState('');
    onAddedPhoto(filename);
    setPostImageFilename(filename);
  };
  return {
    hasImage,
    setHasImage,
    postButtonState,
    setPostButtonState,
    postImageFilename,
    setPostImageFilename,
    handleUploadPhoto,
  };
```

Then use *that* all over the place:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const onAddedPhoto = () => {
    // ...
  };
  const {
    hasImage,
    setHasImage,
    postButtonState,
    setPostButtonState,
    postImageFilename,
    setPostImageFilename,
    handleUploadPhoto,
  } = useImageStuff(onAddedPhoto);
  // ...
```